# VoIP server/client on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, asterisk, voip, freepbx

I'm concerned with intercom station project based on RPi and playing now around Asterisk Server/FreePBX. I'm using RasPBX image on SD card. My intention is to use Raspberry Pi, mounted in some box outside the house, as a platform to be able to communicate with guests outside, when someone is pushing the button.

My question is: Can I run VoIP server and client on the same RPi platform?

I saw it possible on Windows, so on Linux should be also feasible. 
We are talking about running pure VoIP client (Yate, X-Lite...) along with Asterisk Server. 
Which of them will work under GUI and console? 
I'm also interested, how can I script that in python, which library would you recommend? 
Have you got any experience in this area?

I found some info:
http://opensource.telkomspeedy.com/wiki/index.php/VoIP_Cookbook:_Asterisk_as_SIP_Client
, but there is only how Asterisk can be registered itself TO ANOTHER SIP server and became a client. 
I want to set up SIP client and Asterisk server on the same machine and SIP client is calling Asterisk server, so in fact the same device, NOT another one.

Comment: Why don't you try it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run SIP client and Asterisk on same system or server. You just need to make sure that Asterisk and Sip client use different ports.

Here you can find some input for installing SIP clients on raspberry PI:

[SIP-Client for Raspberry Pi that works from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435648/sip-client-for-raspberry-pi-that-works-from-command-line)

For installing Asterisk you might use following manual:

http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/

Comment: Ok, SIP protocol runs normally on 5060. If I'm already running 5060 on Asterisk, which one can I use on SIP client then?

Comment: Any port, probably it is good idea to use non-restricted port(>1024). Just make sure that this port is not used by any other application. Command "netstat -n -l" will show what port are used on your Linux system by all apps, take on account only ports what have state "LISTEN". Those ports are occupied. Some SIP clients may choice to use random port and then you don't care about this issue, for some apps you need to make sure that it will use random port and some may run by default on 5060 and in this case you will run in troubles if you will not update config.